# Como pegar valor de input com clique na div(varias divs com mesma classe) com jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
<div class='premios text-center col-xs-12'>
      <div class='div-img-premio'>
            <img class='img-premio img-responsive' src='$imagem'>
      </div>
      <p class='nome-premio'>".$nome."</p>
      <p class='preco-premio'>".$preco."</p>
      <input class='idPremio' type='hidden' value='$id'>
</div>
```

Quero pegar o valor do `.idPremio`, quando acontecer um clique na .premios, porém tenho varias divs .premios.
Posso clicar em qualquer div, mas sempre vem o valor do primeiro `.idPremio.`
Obrigado.

Comment: o que vc já tentou?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você quer pegar um elemento filho em `.premios,` use a função [**`children()`**](https://api.jquery.com/children/):

```js
$(function(){

  $('.premios').on('click',function(){
    var id = $(this).children('.idPremio').val();
    alert(id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='premios text-center col-xs-12'>
  <div class='div-img-premio'>
    <img class='img-premio img-responsive' src='Imagem1'>
  </div>
  <p class='nome-premio'>nome1</p>
  <p class='preco-premio'>preço1</p>
  <input class='idPremio' type='hidden' value='id1'>
</div>

<div class='premios text-center col-xs-12'>
  <div class='div-img-premio'>
    <img class='img-premio img-responsive' src='Imagem2'>
  </div>
  <p class='nome-premio'>nome2</p>
  <p class='preco-premio'>preço2</p>
  <input class='idPremio' type='hidden' value='id2'>
</div>
```

Comment: valeu, funcionou perfeito.

Answer (score 1):

Tente pegar a classe `idPremio` mais proxima:

```
$( ".premios" ).click(function(){

      valor = $( this ).closest( ".idPremio" ).val();

});
```

ou tente encontrar assim:

```
$( ".premios" ).click(function(){

      valor = $( this ).find( ".idPremio" ).val();

});
```